# Different Type Of Input Based From Their Position

Tags: php, html, foreach

How to create different types of input depends upon their position. For example the following data below.
For every nominees with president and vice-president position display `radio` type of button and if senator position display check box.

I do the following way but does not work.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|candidatesid | studentsname        | position       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|1            |Demnok Lannik        |SENATORS        |
|2            |Aurel Vlaicu         |SENATORS        |
|3            |Rizzrack             |SENATORS        |
|4            |Ymir                 |SENATORS        |
|5            |Raigor Stonehoof     |SENATORS        |
|6            |Kardel Sharpeye      |VICE-PRESIDENT  |
|7            |Purist Thunderwrath  |VICE-PRESIDENT  |
|8            |Razzil Darkbrew      |VICE-PRESIDENT  |
|9            |Aggron Stonebreak    |PRESIDENT       |
|10           |Rylai Crestfall      |PRESIDENT       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

RESULT

**PRESIDENT**
O Aggron Stonebreak 
O Rylai Crestfall

**VICE-PRESIDENT**
O Razzil Darkbrew 
O Purist Thunderwrath
O Kardel Sharpeye

**SENATORS**
[  ] Demnok Lannik
[  ] Aurel Vlaicu  
[  ] Rizzrack  
[  ] Ymir  
[  ] Raigor Stonehoof

MY CODE

```
$arr = array($row['position']);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo '<div class="radio"><label><input class="p" type="radio" name="radio" value="'.$value.'">'.$row['studentsname'].'</label></div>';
}
```

Comment: So does your solution work?

Comment: It work but not as my expected result. It only display all radio button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if ($row['position'] = PRESIDENT)

you must use == so:

```
if ($row['position'] == "PRESIDENT")
```

and other elseifs must be as above

Comment: a useful tip to prevent these kind of mistake: use the condition the other way round. Because a string cannot be assigned, it will cause an error if you forget one "=": `if ("PRESIDENT" == $row['position'])`

Comment: @Ailyn Have you corrected the other `elseif` conditions, i.e. `=="VICE-PRESIDENT"` & `=="SENATORS"`?

Comment: Your ifs must be so:
if ($row['position'] == "PRESIDENT")
elseif($row['position'] == "VICE-PRESIDENT")
elseif($row['position'] == "SENATORS")

Comment: I need to display every nominees but if their position is PRESIDENT AND VICE PRESIDENT I need to use RADIO BUTTON and if SENATORS checkbox.@RasadHasanzada

Comment: in your code it will work just first if..because your any result for example PRESIDENT or  VICE-PRESIDENT or SENATORS equalize PRESİDENT..that s for you must use as above

Comment: I edited my answer. I think the best to use is `foreach` to display all nominees@RasadHasanzada

Comment: please write your all codes here because we dont know what you do it